# Making application visible to software audit tools

Tags: windows, installation

I'm writing a software for Windows which is not always installed via msi installer. The software is aimed for business customers. Bigger companies use tools to audit software installed on employee machines.

My question is: Is there any standard way to make my software visible to these tools. Perhaps there is a place in Windows Registry where I should register my application?

Comment: You would need to know what audit tools exactly are being used.  You would then have to invest in those tools to test your software.  There is no universal answer to this question.  Every audit tool is different.

Answer (score 2):

your best bet is to make an installer that installs it properly, as it will update the registry in the right place(s) to be detected.

Otherwise there's no way to guarantee that any given tool will be able to figure out if it's installed, or just files sitting there.

Related SU Q/A: [How to audit all the software installed on a PC](https://superuser.com/questions/209761/how-to-audit-all-the-software-installed-on-a-pc?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to make a proper installer (writing an add-in for third-party tool and have no control over installation).